# Cascade delete rules in `many to many` relationships in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship, cascade

I have 2 entities: `CD` and `Song`.

`CD1` has songs: `Song1` and `Song2`.
`CD2` has songs: `Song1`.
`CD3` has songs: `Song3`.

Relationships:

`CD` <<-->> `Song` (*many to many*)
`CD` may have a lot of `Songs`, and one `Song` may belong to a few `CD`'s.

Delete rules for `CD`: **Cascade** to `Song`
Delete rules for `Song`: **Nullify** `CD`

What happens If I:

remove `CD1`: *will remove `Song2`*, **what about `Song1`?**
remove `CD2`: **will remove `Song1`?**
remove `CD3`: *will remove `Song3`*

Comment: "Song may have only one CD" so `Song1` can't be both on CD1 and CD2

Comment: you are right... I changed a question...

Comment: But now it doesn't make sense anymore. "Delete rules for CD: Cascade": cascade to what? "Delete rules for Song: Nullify" nullify what?

Comment: @GertArnold It makes sense. When a cd is deleted all its songs get deleted. When a song is deleted it gets removed from the songs set of its CDs.

Comment: @GertArnold I believe this is how coredata handles deletion. You can create an experimental app to verify.

Comment: OK, I (rather sheepishly) have to admit that Coredata indeed implements this cascade rule on many to many associations. I think that's very dangerous though and I can't think of a business case in which that would be desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CD1 has songs: Song1 and Song2.
CD2 has songs: Song1.**

Looks like the relationship between CDs and Songs should be many to many.

**Answer to your question:**

When CD1 is removed Song1 will be removed, regardless of CD2.

Comment: So, If I remove `CD1`, then `CD2` is going to be empty?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk YES